# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - OData Loop

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, npgsql, nettopologysuite

Could anyone help me with something I have been stuck on for a few days now. I am using Odata with asp.net core and NetTopologySuite.

I have a postgres database with column type Geometry. The request with npgsql works fine but the serialization by Odata is a mess.

It seems that odata is looping. I should only receive one XYZ per returned item.

Any suggestions?

This is what is returned.

> ,"shape":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","SRID":4326,"Coordinates":[{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":{"X":-9.129147,"Y":41.133908999999996,"Z":"NaN","M":"NaN","CoordinateValue":
> Blockquote

**Model**

```
       public class Model_bs_age_depth {
    
          
            
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
            public string age_depth_id { get; set; }
            public string site_id { get; set; }
            public string site_type { get; set; }
            public string site_name { get; set; }
            public decimal? latitude { get; set; }
            public decimal? longitude { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point shape { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Model_bs_age_depth>>> Getbs_age_depth() {
    
     var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StorageBroker>()
                    .UseNpgsql(_connectionString, x => 
                     x.UseNetTopologySuite())
                    .UseLoggerFactory(factoryLogger)
                    .Options;
    
                        StorageBroker context = new StorageBroker(optionsBuilder);

   var query = await context.bs_age_depth.ToListAsync();
            
            
            if (query == null) {
                }
            return query;
            }
```

**Storage Broker**

```
   public class StorageBroker : DbContext {

        private static readonly ILoggerFactory factoryLogger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole())!;
        public StorageBroker(DbContextOptions<StorageBroker> options)
           : base(options) {



        }

        public DbSet<Model_bs_age_depth> bs_age_depth { get; set; }
        public DbSet<bs_biozone> bs_biozone { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DBModel> cd_site { get; set; }


       
  

    }

}
```

Debug showing query

> Blockquote
> Entity Framework Core 3.1.20 initialized 'StorageBroker' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: using NetTopologySuite
> info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
> Executed DbCommand (39ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> SELECT b.age_depth_id, b.age_epoch_top, b.age_ma, b.age_period_base, b.age_period_top, b.age_stage_base, b.basin_id, b.basin_name, b.boundary, b.country, b.depth, b.depth_f, b.field_id, b.field_name, b.interpretation_version, b.latitude, b.lithostrat_formation, b.lithostrat_group, b.lithostrat_member, b.location, b.longitude, b.product_id, b.product_title, b.product_year, b.province_state, b.region_id, b.region_name, b.shape, b.site_id, b.site_name, b.site_type, b.table_meta_id, b.tvd_base, b.tvd_base_f, b.tvd_top, b.tvd_top_f
> FROM bs_age_depth AS b
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> Microsoft.OData.ODataException: The depth limit for entries in nested expanded navigation links was reached. The number of nested expanded entries cannot exceed 100.

Comment: `OData` is a protocol, not a library. What library do you use, which version? Are you sure it supports Spatial data in the first place? What does your code do? Do you have a controller or endpoint? Does your action/endpoint return an `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` ? What does the *query* look like?

Comment: Hi Panagiotis. I am using OData.Core 7.9.3. Yes I am sure it supports spatial data, according to documentation. I have a controller with a IEnumerable Task.  I will update the question to include the query now

Comment: do you mean [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/8.0.3)? The latest version is 8.0.3. Both the 7.9 and 8.0 versions have quirks.

Comment: The code you posted is registration code, not query code. It should appear only in `Startup.cs`.  What does `Model_bs_age_depth` look like? Is there any recursion? And what does the actual query code do? An `IEnumerable` is the *result* of a query, not the query itself. You could use `ToList()` to read all the data and convert it to a list of items.

Comment: I have it in the controller because I have to run a check to see who is logged in via Azure AD, at start up they aren't authenticated. I followed this youtube video to get set up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoDJnEwkYOE&t=1086s&ab_channel=HassanHabib .  Model_bs_age_depth contains a list of other postgres column names. I have updated to show.

Comment: Also noticed that the query is populated with the correct data - so it is at the point of odata taking those values that it isnt working.

Comment: And yet, the error says there are recursive navigation links.`The depth limit for entries in nested expanded navigation links was reached.`.  What does your DbContext and OData model code look like? Have you specified any relations? What does the OData query do? Did you use `$expand` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238595/discussion-between-mike-and-panagiotis-kanavos).